# Set Theory Proof with complements - If $A\backslash B$ is a subset of $C$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B$, and $C$ be sets. If $A\backslash B$ is a subset of $C$, then $A\backslash C$ is a subset of $B$. Is this a direct proof where I let $x$ be an element of $A$ and then work from there? I can't seem to figure out all of the cases. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a direct proof style ( let x be...) but you may also prove it manipulating only sets : 
We have $A\setminus B = A \cap B^c \subset C\implies C^c \subset A^c \cup B \implies C^c \cap A \subset A \cap(A^c \cup B)=(A\cap A^c)\cup (A\cap B)=\emptyset \cup (A\cap B)=A\cap B \subset B$ so we finally have $A\setminus C \subset B$. (Try to understand every step that was taken here it may give some intuition about those type of proofs)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to prove $A \setminus C \subseteq B$, start with an element $x \in A \setminus C$, that is $a \in A$, $a \not\in C$. Then either $x \in B$, or $x \not\in B$. If $x \not\in B$, then $x \in A \setminus B$, hence $x \in C$, which is not possible. If $x \in B$, we are done.

Hence $A \setminus C \subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in A \setminus C$, then $x \in A$, but $x \notin C$. If $x \notin B$, then $x \in C$ (because $A \setminus B \subset C$), which is a contradiction. Thus $x \in B$ and $A \setminus C \subset B$.

Comment: How is  A∖B⊂C a contradiction? If you assumed x∉C, how can you later say that x∈C

Comment: We assume that $x \in A \setminus C$. Thus $x \notin C$. Now we want to see if $x$ is in $B$ or not. Suppose not. Then $x \in A \setminus B \subset C$, thus $x \in C$, which cannot be (this is the contradiction). So $x \in B$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from a simple equivalence of propositional formulas:
$$
(p \land \neg q) \to r \equiv (p \land \neg r) \to q. \tag{1}
$$
Take $p := x\in A, q := x\in B, r := x\in C$.
In turn, (1) follows from
$$
(u \land v) \to w \equiv u \to (v \to w) \tag{2}
$$
and 
$$
v \to w \equiv \neg v \to \neg w. \tag{3}
$$